# How do I get a projection of rs.status() that includes just { name, stateStr, optimeDate }

Tags: mongodb

I want to reduce the output from the rs.status() method so I am presented with just name, stateStr, and optimeDate from each of the members.  Is there a way to do this?  rs.status() is just backed by some collection somewhere, what is it and how can I query it directly.  Effectively what I want is like...

```
PRIMARY> rs.status().pretty( {members.name: 1, members.stateStr: 1, members.optimeDate: 1 } );
{
    "name" : "mongo1.rek.tc",
    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-09-06T17:28:19Z")
},
{
    "name" : "mongo2.rek.tc",
    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-09-06T17:28:14Z")
},
{
    "name" : "mongo3.rek.tc",
    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-09-06T17:28:15Z")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a projection against the $cmd namespace it seems.  I tried on the translated query from the helper, namely:

```
 db.$cmd.findOne( { replSetGetStatus : 1 })
```

It still won't let me project the results.  Even if that was possible, projections to return multiple sub-elements of arrays (members is an array) don't work too well either, so even if the projection worked you would have issues.

You can do this with a bit of simple javascript.  The below works, but you may want to add more formatting and the field names if it is useful to you:

```
rs.status().members.forEach( 
    function(z){ 
            printjson(z.name);
            printjson(z.stateStr);
            printjson(z.optimeDate); 
    } 
   )
```

Comment: That works pretty well.  I'm changing it to get the content all on one line per member, but the concept is great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From command line:

```
mongo --eval "rs.status()" | grep "name\|stateStr\|optimeDate"
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need JavaScript or Linux, you can try;

```
rs.status().members.forEach(function (m) { print(m.name.split(":").shift()); print(m.stateStr); print(m.uptime) })
```